# Catching an error at compile rather than run time in Java

Tags: java, object

I had a method (call it foo) like this:  public void foo (String parm)
I know have occasion to sometimes require an Integer which I will convert to a String (not just "" + x, it is more complicated than that and you cannot determine the String value just by looking at the int value.  The int value will be used as an index.

So now I do this:

```
public void foo(Object obj) {
 if (obj instanceof String) {
     ...
 } else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
     ...
 } else // some sort of error
}
```

which will not catch an error at compile time if you do something like:

```
foo(new Date());
```

Is there a way I can catch this at compile time (other than making two separate methods `public void foo(Integer x)` and `public void foo (String str)`?

Comment: overload your method. One that takes String and other that takes Integer.

Comment: "*other than making two separate methods*" what's the problem with doing that? Overloading is exactly how you handle type inconsistencies at compile-time. What are you hoping for exactly? Generally speaking it's a bad sign if you have a method that accepts different types of input and does different things with them. Define two separate methods instead.

Comment: Although you *could* achieve this in C++ (this sort-of legitimises this question IMHO) you can't do it in Java. Any solution will boil down to having exactly two overloaded functions.

Comment: This is a simplification but basically
public void foo (Object obj) {
int ind = 0;
String str = null;
if (obj indexof Integer) {
ind = (Integer) obj;
str = someList.get(ind);
} else if (obj instanceof String) {
str = (String) obj;
}

And I have 7 or 8 of these so I could double them and maybe that is the best solution, but there are many to do.

Comment: Overloading the method is the way to tell the compiler which parameter types are acceptable.

Comment: @Tony whether you use a chain of `instanceof` or overloaded methods, you will have a lot to do either way.

Comment: People said the same thing.  Not sure which to choose ;-)  Although I guess the first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, build *overloaded* versions of `foo`:

`foo(String obj)`

`foo(Integer obj)`

and remove the general one. Have those call a general (`private`) `_foo(Object obj)` if you must.

Answer (score 0):

I would even go one step further; not only should you have two methods (one taking a string, one taking an Integer) ... you should give those methods two different names.

You want to follow [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (single responsibility principle). Any element (classes, methods) in your code should be responsible for exactly "one thing".

And the names of your classes and methods should make it very clear what they are supposed to do. And in that sense, it would seem awkward that you have two methods with the same name and different parameters. Because, in essence, those two methods would be doing different things. So - give them names that say what they really do.

Comment: They really do basically the same thing.  There is a list of offices on the screen, each has an ID.  The method (it actually is not void) returns information about the office.  If you pass a string it will return it for that office, and if you pass an integer it will take that + 1 (i.e. if the offices in order are "111112", "231222", "123456" and you pass in 0 it will get the info for "111112", pass in a 1 will return info for "231222", etc.

Comment: I have often wondered why it is necessary to have the same name for two methods with different parameters.  They could just have some slightly more descriptive name.

Answer (score 0):

It will not catch an error because there isn't an error.
You are allowing an object to be passed as an argument, and like you know, all objects are based off the class Object, so `new Date()` is an instance of Object.
I would recommend creating the two methods, as this would keep the code cleaner.